# Xdebug wizard error

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

once downloaded the 2.2.3 xdebug dll and replaced it with the outdated one in php-ini, i seem to be getting an error in the xdebug wizard saying

Summary

```
Xdebug installed: 2.2.3
Server API: Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.7
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext

( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: xdebugVersion::$xdebugVersionToInstall in /var/www/servers/xdebug.org/html/wizard.php on line 42
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  352648  {main}( )   ../wizard.php:0
You're already running the latest Xdebug version
```

any help would be very much appreacited and once i try to use a framework i get this error:  Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration API220100525,TS,VC9, where as running engine is API220100525,NTS,VC9, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you loaded the incorrect version. Your PHP install is compiled as NTS - not thread safe, while your xdebug is compiled TS - thread safe. You need to make sure the compile environments are identical

Comment: So would you suggest me uninstalling php and downloading the thread safe version?

Comment: and could please someone elaborate on why thread safe is enabled which leads me to assume that this version of php is thread safe?

Comment: its fine now i have fixed it by applying the downloaded settings to the current php version on my pc.simple solution really much appreciated for the help.